# How can we start simple harmonic motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

I have a great deal of problem in understanding simple harmonic motion. Do we have to displace  a spring-mass  system from its equilibrium position or create disturbance to start simple harmonic motion?

Comment: What is an shm? I assume it is some abbreviation for something, but I don't know that, and it would be good to readers of your question to know.

Comment: Assuming "shm" means "simple harmonic motion" from the context, the answer is that we can start the motion by giving it either an initial velocity or displacement, that is $\dot{x}(t=0)=v_0$ or $x(t=0)=x_0$. It's also possible to impose both initial conditions at the same time, by giving it both an initial displacement and momentum.

Comment: Nature is not perfect. Everything not need to be in equilibrium even classically.

Comment: @SaksithJaksri Everything need not be in equilibrium, but it doesn't mean you can't analyze situations where they are.

Comment: -1. Unclear what your problem is. Simple answer : Yes. What is your difficulty? Are you thinking of some other method? Or that these methods do not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to observe it, yes.

Unforced SHM is described by the differential equation $ m \ddot x - kx = 0$.  The solution for $x (t) $ depends on the initial conditions.

When there is no force or initial displacement applied, the differential equation is satisfied by using $m \ddot x = kx = 0$.  You could describe it as a harmonic motion with an amplitude of 0, but that's the same as not moving.